# Is AppContainer available on Azure / Windows Server?

Tags: azure, windows-8, appcontainer

Windows 8 AppContainer appears to provide an attractive sandboxing/process isolation model. Is it available on Windows Azure? Windows Azure cloud service instances seem to run a version of Windows Server. I would like to provide some isolation for the user code we run on those instances, and the only working option so far has been running the code in .NET partial trust, which has big limitations. Are there perhaps other options?